# Security considerations for read.csv() from web url in R?

Tags: r, read.csv

A lot of R's `read*` functions permit urls to external data sources.

Are there any built in protections in R itself or in R's read* functions to protect against malicious files being read in? Or is it a case of 'user-beware'?

#### What I know so far

We could run some tests - e.g. a file that is *not* a csv e.g. `read.csv(url("http://www.hello.com"))` returns the raw HTML for that web page. This seems to indicate that `read.csv` doesn't validate that the file is a csv, but tries to parse it regardless.

I am not sure what would happen in the hypothetical `read.csv(url("www.fake-microsoft.com/nasty-viris.exe"))` (where `virus.exe` is a real virus)? Would `read.csv()` try to read the asset (in this case an `exe` file) as a csv, or would it download it successfully first?

Short of setting up a virtual machine and actually testing, I am not sure how to research how much vetting (if any) is done by `read*` functions on external data sources.

Comment: Hi, Is it possible for you to just check file using ```list.files()``` and then consider those only which you want ? will be better to eliminate csv which is not useful.

Comment: @TusharLad I guess what I'm interested in is whether someone (malicious) could place a virus at a url where a legitimate `csv` or `rds` file used to be, meaning anyone using those urls could be at risk of unknowingly downloading a malicious file. Or would that just fail due to some built in protections in `read*()` / R / OS?

Comment: I think what would ultimately have to happen is a way to trick R into parsing the comma-delimited rows, then trigger something (e.g., a nul in some streams) that causes R to rewrite some of that data into the execution stack and attempt to execute it. Ergo, a literal stack overflow. Is it possible? I cannot say it's impossible, but it seems rather remote, looking at the source code for [`read.csv`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/library/utils/R/readtable.R).

Comment: @r2evans interesting. Do you mean it would be remote/difficult for that to happen *by accident* (e.g. a corrupt csv file), or do you mean it would be difficult even if attempted intentionally? (I'm more interested in how exposed R's read functions are to *intentional* exploitation)

Comment: I'm saying the possibility of it happening at all is remote, intentional or otherwise. I don't know if it is possible. I don't know if anyone has done any "fuzzing"; that might be one way to test it. (I *believe* it is completely safe, but that is unverified. Faith.)

Comment: Regardless, I believe the `read.*` functions do nothing to verify the type of file before reading (some of) it. They tend to verify it is (say) a whitespace-delimited file by pressing it as such, and determining it is not formatted correctly when a passing error occurs (too many columns found in a row).

Comment: I believe that the `read.*` family of functions is simply too "dumb" (in the good way - does a simple task well) to be useful for that kind of attack. Since the data doesn't seem to be parsed as language, only dropped into a storage, it looks safe. Life is full of surprises, but this would be a big surprise.